# Fundamental group to groupoid : bijection between homotopy classes?

Tags: homotopy-theory, fundamental-group, braid-groups, configuration-spaces

I'm looking at the fundamental group $\pi_{1}(M)$ of the $n^{th}$ unordered configuration space $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. In particular, it's well-known that $\pi_{1}(M)\cong S_{n}$ (symmetric group) for $d\geq3$ and $\pi_{1}(M)\cong B_{n}$ (braid group) for $d=2$.

Let $\Pi(a,b)$ denote the homotopy classes of paths from $a$ to $b$ in $M$ (for some $M$ as described above). We know $\Pi(a,a)\cong \pi_{1}(M)$ for any $a\in M$ (since $M$ is connected).

**Question:**
For any $a,b\in M$, does there exist a bijection $h:\Pi(a,a)\to\Pi(a,b)$ that respects composition in the obvious way? That is, $h:[g]^{(a,a)}\mapsto[g]^{(a,b)}$ such that $[g_{2}]^{(b,c)}\circ[g_{1}]^{(a,b)}=[g_2 g_1]^{(a,c)}\in\Pi(a,c)$ ? (Have $g,g_1,g_2\in\pi_{1}(M)$).

**Comments**: For a while I've thought the answer would be yes, but a concrete argument or reference would be much appreciated (or a refutation if that's the case!). I have a very rough sketch for why this might be true (involving the idea that it should suffice to consider moving one of $n$ points within a subregion of $\mathbb{R}^d$ (where adjacent points lie on the boundary), and that the homotopy classes from the fundamental group would be preserved under deformations within such a region).

Comment: I'm not clear on what your notation denotes (can you say what $[g]^{(a,b)}$ is defined as?), But a choice of (homotopy class of) path from $b$ to $a$ defines a bijection of $\pi_1(M)$-sets $\Pi(a,b)\to \Pi(a,a)$, where the action is concatenation of (homotopy classes of) paths and loops. Both of these $\pi_1(M)$-actions are transitive and free. This is statement purely about groupoids, nothing to do with your example.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @theHigherGeometer. $[g]^{(a,b)}$ was intended to denote the image of $g$ under $h_{ab}$ as defined in Neil Strickland's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fix a basepoint $a$ and choose a path $u_x$ from $a$ to $x$ for each $x$.  Then define $h_{xy}\colon \Pi(a,a)\to\Pi(x,y)$ by $h_{xy}(p)=u_y\circ p\circ u_x^{-1}$.  These maps are bijections and satisfy $h_{yz}(q)\circ h_{xy}(p)=h_{xz}(q\circ p)$.  This is an instance of the general fact that any connected groupoid is equivalent to a one-object groupoid.  In particular, this is nothing to do with the particular space $M$, apart from the fact that $M$ is path-connected.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for the quick response - that makes perfect sense. I was going to ask what the general criterion for this being true was as a follow-up but you've already sorted that out. Have a nice day!